# Android Studio SDK Managed Disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I just downloaded the Android Studio .dmg for OSX.  Per the installation instructions, I've dragged it to the application folder and launched the application.

But the SDK Manager and AVD Manager are greyed out and are impossible to use.

Any ideas on an installation step I may have missed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A project needs to have been loaded at least once for the link to become available.

Found it in :
File / Project Structure... 
Then in "Android SDK" provide the path to the SDK folder inside the Android Studio Application Bundle.
Then Make a new project.
Then after the initial setup the elements where finally enabled.

Comment: When I followed all of the steps outlined by other contributors the sdk icon still didn't work on an existing project. Only after I started a new project did it then work.

Answer (score 39):

For people coming for this same problem for *Windows*: you won't have an Android SDK anywhere if it is your first time with Android. Also, here the Android Studio doesn't come with a packed SDK Manager, so you need to download one.

So this is what you may do:

## Download the SDK Manager and an Android SDK

1. Download the SDK Manager from: http://developer.android.com/sdk/. Use the link that says "Get the SDK for an existing IDE".
2. Execute the downloaded installer.
3. Execute this program with administrator rights: SDK Manager.exe
4. Download the proposed SDK (if you get errors regarding the SDK Manager couldn't create some folders, remember it should be executed as administrator).

## Configure Android Studio to work with the new SDK

1. Open Android Studio and in the Quick Start window click "Configure", you will see the SDK Manager greyed out.
2. Go to "Project Defaults", then to "Project Structure" and there it will ask for the path where you installed the SDK.
3. If you click OK and go back you will see the SDK Manager is no longer greyed out, and now you can start creating projects.

Answer (score 9):

Android Studio Beta v0.8.14 with the Android SDK for Mac does *not* appear to include the SDK: you need to install the SDK manually (e.g. https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools) and then configure Android Studio to find and use it.

(I ended up using the ADT bundle, since I couldn't seem to find the SDK as a standalone download.)

You need to use the buttons on the welcome dialog, and not on the applications menu bar or preferences (as I had initially thought). Step by step:

[image: Welcome to Android Studio]

[image: Configure panel]

(Note that "SDK Manager" is greyed out until you complete this, at which point you cannot undo it for the purposes of taking screenshots...)

[image: Project Defaults panel]

[image: Project Structure dialog]

Navigate back and the "SDK Manager" button on the "Configure" panel should be enabled. Clicking it should display something like this:

[image: Android SDK Manager]

Comment: This worked for me with Android Studio 3.0.1. (on Mac) even though it is a newer version than your screenshots reflect, it worked all the same way, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and the cause was that I've used path with a space in it. There was a warning in the window that can cause problems with NDK, but in fact it caused problems with Android Studio internal SDK as well. After changing the path it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Go to configure -> project defaults -> project structure

give the path for the SDK and press OK.

It should work now

Answer (score 1):

**For Mac Users** (Android Studio Beta v0.8.14)

The SDK or SDK manager is not included with this version of Android Studio, and the documentation is obfuscated regarding this change at this point.

1. Download the standalone SDK from [here](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23.0.2-macosx.zip). You may select the latest revision of the same from this [link](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) below the title ***GET THE SDK FOR AN EXISTING IDE***.
2. Extract the downloaded zip, and rename the folder as `sdk`
3. Copy the `sdk` folder into the `Android Studio.app/Contents` directory
4. Restart Android Studio and you will be shown this dialog when the Android Studio starts up

[image]

Comment: "and the documentation is obfuscated" so is any Google-related product doc. They clearly should learn how to properly write documentation with Facebook. Anyway here's a tip: if you've already tried downloading the SDK through Android Studio, your desired 'sdk' folder that must be copied is probably in /Users/<you>/Library/Android. Tho it didn't work for me...

Answer (score 1):

To remove grey out area,

you need to follow this steps as below:

1. Go to File
2. Click on Project Structure
3. Go to SDK Location
4. Click on Browse to find SDK path
5. Select proper SDK path on your system
6. Now click on SDK manager icon on Android Studio toolbar

I hope this solves the problem of grey out area.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This will no longer be a problem when version 1.0 is released. In the meanwhile you can download the [latest canary build](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest) (1.0 RC2), which downloads the SDK during the setup.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was on windows and it was as simple as launching the installer with "administrative" mode. That's it!