# How to install Android Marshmallow on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, android-6.0-marshmallow

Just downloaded Android Studio but need an Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) SDK, so in the “Welcome to Android Studio” screen, launched the SDK Manager.
In the SDK Manager, went to “System Settings” -> “Android SDK”, and I see Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) SDK and other SDK’s as well, but they are all greyed-out.

How can I install the Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) SDK?

Thank you and will be sure to accept the answer and upvote as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio, go to Tools -> SDK Manager and select all the different API's you want to download.

Comment: are you referring to SDK Tools tab next to SDK Platforms? I went to Tools but only see Web Browsers, External Tools, Diff, Server Certificates, and Settings Repository

Comment: Can you select different APIs to download by clicking the checkmark in the SDK Platforms tab?

Comment: @JessueBuss please take a look at the original post. Made an edit with the screenshot. All the checkboxes are greyed out.

Comment: Ah okay. In that case follow these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26813635/6214984

Comment: Appreciate the lead but it is referring to Windows users. Would it be applied the same to Mac users?

Comment: If you already have the SDK downloaded, could you verify that you have the SDK location set up properly?  It's under

File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location

Comment: For the downloaded SDK, are you referring to Marshmallow? Also, where can I locate File, is it under Preferences?

Comment: You should download the Android SDK and use that path

Comment: Just checking in to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.

Comment: I can tell from the screenshot that you don't have the sdk path set up.  It is normally installed to the `/Users/<name>/Library/Android/sdk/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

By checking your posted screenshot the SDK path was missing. Click on Edit button and select your SDK path that you selected while installing Android Studio in your system.

For instance in Windows if you're not selecting any SDK installation path the Android Studio installs it in

```
C:\Users\<your_name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

(mostly you're using MacOS. So, check it in `/Users/<your_name>/Library/Android/sdk/`)

And click Ok. Now you can download any API version of Android SDK. In order to do that just check the checkbox and hit install.

Answer (score 0):

just go to sdk manager and download the api level 23

Comment: Where can I locate it?