# Can't set Android NDK version on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

When I try setting ndk version on android studio, via project structure -> sdk location, the search box is grayed out.
So I went to the local.properties file, and set ndk.dir there. But the issue is that when I do this, android studio can't sync gradle, and it constantly throws me this "SILLY ERROR"

> Gradle sync failed: exception during working with external system:

I tried setting system environment variable for the ndk directory, but it still didn't function !!!!!!!

This IDE is frustrating. where should I set my NDK version then ? I stuck and every solution I try online doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The recent version of Android Gradle Plugin expect you to install NDK [(side by side)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348606/192373) via the SDK Manager, and choose the version for your module in **build.gradle**:

```
android {
    …
    android.ndkVersion '19.2.5345600'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But when I do that, I get this error "Could not find method ndkVersion() for arguments [21.3.6528147] on project "

Comment: See [https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1313#issuecomment-656826716] and upgrade your Android Gradle Plugin.

Answer (score -2):

The reason that your SDK location is grayed out might be because you don't have one installed.

I found this question asked earlier that can help you solve this problem:

[Android Studio SDK Managed Disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375881/android-studio-sdk-managed-disabled/26813635)

Comment: NDK, not SDK . .